# How To Calculate The Implied One Day Expected Return For Earnings

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the one day expected return given I have the event volatility. In his book *Trading Volatility, Correlation, Term Structure and Skew*, Collin Bennet ([link](http://www.trading-volatility.com/Trading-Volatility.pdf)) explains how to calculate the one day expected return given we already calculated the event volatility. However, I am not too sure how to use the $N(\sigma)$ in the formula on Page 247:

$$\operatorname{Expected daily return} = e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}} \left[ 2 \cdot N(\sigma) -1 \right]$$

Do I have to run simulations and calculate the expected value of the straddle?

Assuming our event volatility is 100% would someone be able to help me make sense of this formula?

The event volatility was calculated by solving for non-event vol and subtracting it from current ivol. Below is the formula from Page 180.

$$\sigma_{\operatorname{Jump}} = \sqrt{\sigma_{\operatorname{Expiry after Jump}}^2 \cdot T - \sigma_{\operatorname{Diffusive}}^2 \cdot  (T-1)}$$

where $\sigma_{\operatorname{Expiry after Jump}}$ denotes the implied volatility of an option whose expiry is after the jump, $T$ is the time to the expiry after jump ($=T_1$), $\sigma_{\operatorname{Diffusive}}$ is the diffusive volatility and $\sigma_{\operatorname{Jump}}$ is the implied volatility due to the jump.

Comment: Did you figure out how to apply the expected daily return formula?